# Initial ASP.NET MVC Load Slow due to byte[] Image Load from DB - Possible Async Load?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, model-view-controller, web-applications

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web Application that in main HomeController()'s constructor loads images from DB byte arrays to ViewModel of the later loaded View().

Each image takes between 4 to 10 seconds to load(1920x1080 around 2,5MB).

Due to large number of images to load into the Model, the initial App load takes even 45 seconds before it starts rendering View().

Is it possible to run byte[] loading from DB using async methods?

I cannot seem to be able to call asynchronous methods from Home Controllers' constructor.

Please help.

Comment: A [mcve] would be great.

Comment: `that in main HomeController()'s constructor loads images from DB byte arrays to ViewModel of the later loaded View().` My tip is 'don't do that'. Databases are not good for storing images. Use S3 or a folder.

Comment: @positiveperspective you can store the filepath to the image on disk in the db and read the image from disk into a byte array. also, as mjwills said, please post all of the relevant code

Comment: so when image is loaded via api, it should not be stored as byte array in db, instead I should save it as file and store path. that will save db space too

Comment: pertaining to your actual question, you could load each necessary image via ajax on load of the page. that way your "first meaningful paint" of the page is quick and all images load afterward

Comment: i need to rewrite image upload code since the file was stored in db as byte array. I will go for storing image as file as it's path be stored in db instead. ajax loader will be good temp solution until I rewrite architecture.

Comment: reading form disk will not solve all your problems as it is still a fairly expensive operation. I imagine you'll want to use ajax, read from disk and if the app ever needs to scale well then the document storage server should be separate than the web server as constantly reading so many images from disk will hit cpu utilization hard.

Comment: @GregH As long as IIS (rather than MVC specifically) is serving up the files then CPU should be OK.

Comment: @mjwills assuming that is due to iis cacheing? could still be an issue depending on how many different images are needed for loading. he mentioned reading from an api so im assuming theres a great deal of them. please correct me if my line of thinking is wrong

Comment: @GregH More that it bypasses the cost of MVC and .NET. A CDN will improve it further, but IIS is quite good at serving static files.

Comment: yes, we are talking about multiple galleries of around 30 images each.

Comment: IIS will handle that easily.

Comment: I am rewriting my nooby code to post image to api, store it in folder and save path to db/return it to client. thanks for pointing this out as I am still in phase where doing it does not cost me a lot

Comment: I agree on the minimal example, but in general this seems like a sub-optimal solution as there are likely other kinds of infrastructure better suited to this. You might look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 if you need to do this.